# Jenkins configuration as a code + SSO SAML: How to generate first API token programmatically?

Tags: jenkins, saml

I'm deploying a new Jenkins from scratch on a single host using Docker all on top of AWS.
Its authentication mode is set to SAML (using Okta) and we configure it using JCasC (Configuration as code).
The deployment strategy we decided is to deploy a new instance each time a configuration change is made. 
However, in order to give a good experience to our end users, we want to make 2 steps before swapping between old and new release:

1. Put the old instance in Quiet mode.
2. Query running builds
3. When running query builds = 0 then swap the instance.
   We have no problem on doing that with the API but... the problem is that we depend on one single thing: the API token!

How do we **programmatically** create and retrieve an API token each time a new Jenkins instance is released when the **authentication mode is set to SAML**?

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem. Did you find a way how to generate an API Token when Jenkins is configured with SAML authentication?